# Uniform sampling within a range of values in a Pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some `DataFrame` of random floats:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0, 100, size=(10000, 1)), columns=list('A'))
```

I'm specifically interested in the rows with values between 50 and 60:

```
df[(df['A'] > 50) & (df['A'] < 60)].hist(bins=100)
```

[image]

I can randomly sample from this distribution:

```
df[(df['A'] > 50) & (df['A'] < 60)].sample(n=50).hist(bins=100)
```

[image]

**Is there a way where I can instead select rows to generate a uniform distribution between these values?**

For example, I would like 51.3, 52.7, 53.4, 57.2, 59.6...etc to be close to evenly represented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone can probably do better, but this is fairly close to what I'm looking for:

```
select = []
for N in range(50, 60):
    select.append(df[(df['A'] < N+1) & (df['A'] > N)].sample(n=50))
```